# Developing commercial apps on Windows from Dreamspark

Tags: windows, dreamspark

May I develop commercial apps on Windows from Dreamspark? I know, that I can't do this using Dreamspark's Visual Studuo, but if I used Mingw?

Answer (score 0):

Dreamspark access for Azure offers only the following services:

- [Web Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-web-overview/)
- [MySQL DB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL)
- [VSO (Visual Studio Online)](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/what-is-visual-studio-online-vs.aspx)
- [Application Insights](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/application-insights/)

More about Azure: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/fundamentals-introduction-to-azure/

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add development apps from DreamSpark to the Windows Store for commercial gain if your a registered student see the EULA At 
https://www.dreamspark.com/Student/Direct-EULA.aspx

see 
. No commercial use.
Except as provided below, you may not use the DreamSpark Direct Subscription software for commercial purposes or commercial software application development, publication or distribution unless you first purchase the appropriate commercial license(s) for the software.
• Windows Phone Application Requirements. To commercially publish and distribute a phone-based software application that you developed using the DreamSpark Subscription software, the application must be submitted through the Windows Phone Dev Center (https://dev.windowsphone.com/) for publication in the Windows Phone Store and comply with all applicable Windows Phone Store Application Provider requirements.
• Windows Application Requirements. To commercially publish and distribute a computer-based software application that you developed using the DreamSpark Subscription software, the application must be published in the Windows Store and comply with all applicable Windows Store Application Developer requirements.
• Xbox LIVE Indie Games Development Requirements. To commercially publish and distribute a console-based game or software application that you developed using the DreamSpark Subscription software, the application must be published to Xbox LIVE Indie Games and comply with all applicable Xbox LIVE Indie Games development requirements.

All Student get a FREE Windows Store Developer Account via DreamSpark.com 
https://www.dreamspark.com/Student/Windows-Store-Access.aspx